# Positioning Unordered List and Items out of Unordered List Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists, positioning

I have a problem about positioning ul elements and arrows in the [demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/) together. I can't put `<div id="ytplayer_div2"></div>` tags between `<ul>` because of elements with id `ytplayer_div2` coming from javascript side which below the [demo page](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/) source. Even if i were put these i couldn't figure out any solution.
where are content inside `<div id="ytplayer_div2"></div>` tags coming from:

```
      function ytplayer_render_playlist( )
  {
    for ( var i = 0; i < ytplayer_playlist.length; i++ )
    {
      var img = document.createElement( "img" );
      img.src = "track_arrow.gif";
      var a = document.createElement( "a" );
      a.href = "#ytplayer";
      a.onclick = (
        function( j )
        {
          return function( )
          {
            ytplayer_playitem = j;
            ytplayer_playlazy( 0 );
          };
        }
      )( i );
      a.appendChild( img );
      document.getElementById( "ytplayer_div2" ).appendChild( a );
    }
  }
```

In short, how can i this [demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/) make into like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pBZA.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

Give the `<ul>` an *id*, e.g. `<ul id="mylist">`, then at the beginning of your function get all of the `<li>` direct children of it,

```
var arrOfListNodes = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementById('mylist').childNodes, function (e) {return e.tagName === 'LI';});
```

and at the end of your function instead of appending to `ytplayer_div2`, do

```
arrOfListNodes[i].insertBefore(a, arrOfListNodes[i].firstChild);
```

The arrows will appear on the right due to your style (`float: left;` on the other elements in the `<li>`s) but are in the correct part of the DOM Tree now.

Comment: Thanks Paul. But if i remove float:left output piffles. I know i go too far.